# Run - Time Error '13': Type Mismatch - excel user form

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I am receiving "Run time error 13" when i try to submit the user form.

```
dTotal1 = CDbl(sval1) + CDbl(sval2) + CDbl(sval3) + CDbl(sval4) + CDbl(sval6)
```

Here is the complete code. Please help.

```
Private Sub AddTextBox()

 Dim sval1 As Variant
 Dim sval2 As String
 Dim sval3 As String
 Dim sval4 As String
 Dim sval5 As String
 Dim sval6 As String
 Dim sval7 As String
 Dim sval8 As String
 Dim sval9 As String
 Dim sval10 As String
 Dim sval11 As String
 Dim sval12 As String
 Dim sval13 As String
 Dim sval14 As String
 Dim sval15 As String
 Dim sval16 As String
 Dim sval17 As String
 Dim sval18 As String
 Dim sval19 As String
 Dim sval20 As String
 Dim sval21 As String
 Dim sval22 As String
 Dim sval23 As String
 Dim sval24 As String
 Dim sval25 As String

 Dim sval100 As String
 Dim sval101 As String
 Dim sval102 As String
 Dim sval103 As String
 Dim sval104 As String

 Dim sval105 As String
 Dim sval106 As String
 Dim sval107 As String
 Dim sval108 As String

 Dim sval109 As String
 Dim sval110 As String
 Dim sval111 As String
 Dim sval112 As String

 Dim sval113 As String
 Dim sval114 As String
 Dim sval115 As String

 Dim sval116 As String
 Dim sval117 As String



 Dim sval31 As String
 Dim sval32 As String
 Dim sval33 As String
 Dim sval34 As String
 Dim sval35 As String
 Dim sval36 As String
 Dim sval37 As String
 Dim sval38 As String
 Dim sval39 As String
 Dim sval40 As String
 Dim sval41 As String
 Dim sval42 As String
 Dim sval43 As String
 Dim sval44 As String
 Dim sval45 As String
 Dim sval46 As String
 Dim sval47 As String
 Dim sval48 As String




 Dim dTotal1 As String
 Dim dTotal2 As String
 Dim dTotal3 As String
 Dim dTotal4 As String
 Dim dTotal5 As String
 Dim dTotal6 As String
 Dim dTotal11 As String
 Dim dTotal12 As String
 Dim dTotal13 As String
 Dim dTotal14 As String
 Dim dTotal15 As String
 Dim dTotal16 As String
 Dim dTotal17 As String

With Me

    sval1 = .CB1.Value
    sval2 = .CB2.Value
    sval3 = .CB3.Value
    sval4 = .CB4.Value
    sval6 = .CB6.Value
    sval100 = .CB1.Value
    sval101 = .CB2.Value
    sval102 = .CB3.Value
    sval103 = .CB4.Value
    sval104 = .CB6.Value
    sval31 = .CB1.Value
    sval32 = .CB2.Value
    sval33 = .CB3.Value
    sval34 = .CB4.Value
    sval35 = .CB6.Value



    sval7 = .CB7.Value
    sval8 = .CB8.Value
    sval9 = .CB9.Value
    sval10 = .CB10.Value
    sval105 = .CB7.Value
    sval106 = .CB8.Value
    sval107 = .CB9.Value
    sval108 = .CB10.Value
    sval36 = .CB7.Value
    sval37 = .CB8.Value
    sval38 = .CB9.Value
    sval39 = .CB10.Value



    sval11 = .CB11.Value
    sval12 = .CB12.Value
    sval13 = .CB13.Value
    sval14 = .CB14.Value
    sval109 = .CB11.Value
    sval110 = .CB12.Value
    sval111 = .CB13.Value
    sval112 = .CB14.Value
    sval40 = .CB11.Value
    sval41 = .CB12.Value
    sval42 = .CB13.Value
    sval43 = .CB14.Value



    sval15 = .CB15.Value
    sval16 = .CB16.Value
    sval17 = .CB17.Value
    sval113 = .CB15.Value
    sval114 = .CB16.Value
    sval115 = .CB17.Value
    sval44 = .CB15.Value
    sval45 = .CB16.Value
    sval46 = .CB17.Value


    sval18 = .CB18.Value
    sval19 = .CB19.Value
    sval116 = .CB18.Value
    sval117 = .CB19.Value
    sval47 = .CB18.Value
    sval48 = .CB19.Value


    If sval1 = "" Or sval1 = "NA" Then sval1 = 0
    If sval2 = "" Or sval2 = "NA" Then sval2 = 0
    If sval3 = "" Or sval3 = "NA" Then sval3 = 0
    If sval4 = "" Or sval4 = "NA" Then sval4 = 0
    If sval6 = "" Or sval6 = "NA" Then sval6 = 0
  If sval100 = "NA" Then sval100 = 0 Else sval100 = 5
  If sval101 = "NA" Then sval101 = 0 Else sval101 = 3
  If sval102 = "NA" Then sval102 = 0 Else sval102 = 3
  If sval103 = "NA" Then sval103 = 0 Else sval103 = 4
  If sval104 = "NA" Then sval104 = 0 Else sval104 = 5
    If sval7 = "" Or sval7 = "NA" Then sval7 = 0
    If sval8 = "" Or sval8 = "NA" Then sval8 = 0
    If sval9 = "" Or sval9 = "NA" Then sval9 = 0
    If sval10 = "" Or sval10 = "NA" Then sval10 = 0
  If sval105 = "NA" Then sval105 = 0 Else sval105 = 7
  If sval106 = "NA" Then sval106 = 0 Else sval106 = 3
  If sval107 = "NA" Then sval107 = 0 Else sval107 = 2
  If sval108 = "NA" Then sval108 = 0 Else sval108 = 2
    If sval11 = "" Or sval11 = "NA" Then sval11 = 0
    If sval12 = "" Or sval12 = "NA" Then sval12 = 0
    If sval13 = "" Or sval13 = "NA" Then sval13 = 0
    If sval14 = "" Or sval14 = "NA" Then sval14 = 0
  If sval109 = "NA" Then sval109 = 0 Else sval109 = 5
  If sval110 = "NA" Then sval110 = 0 Else sval110 = 3
  If sval111 = "NA" Then sval111 = 0 Else sval111 = 8
  If sval112 = "NA" Then sval112 = 0 Else sval112 = 10
    If sval15 = "" Or sval15 = "NA" Then sval15 = 0
    If sval16 = "" Or sval16 = "NA" Then sval16 = 0
    If sval17 = "" Or sval17 = "NA" Then sval17 = 0
  If sval113 = "NA" Then sval113 = 0 Else sval113 = 8
  If sval114 = "NA" Then sval114 = 0 Else sval114 = 10
  If sval115 = "NA" Then sval115 = 0 Else sval115 = 10
    If sval18 = "" Or sval18 = "NA" Then sval18 = 0
    If sval19 = "" Or sval19 = "NA" Then sval19 = 0
  If sval116 = "NA" Then sval116 = 0 Else sval116 = 5
  If sval117 = "NA" Then sval117 = 0 Else sval117 = 7




    dTotal11 = CDbl(sval100) + CDbl(sval101) + CDbl(sval102) + CDbl(sval103) + CDbl(sval104)
    dTotal12 = CDbl(sval105) + CDbl(sval106) + CDbl(sval107) + CDbl(sval108)
    dTotal13 = CDbl(sval109) + CDbl(sval110) + CDbl(sval111) + CDbl(sval112)
    dTotal14 = CDbl(sval113) + CDbl(sval114) + CDbl(sval115)
    dTotal15 = CDbl(sval116) + CDbl(sval117)





    dTotal1 = CDbl(sval1) + CDbl(sval2) + CDbl(sval3) + CDbl(sval4) + CDbl(sval6)
    dTotal2 = CDbl(sval7) + CDbl(sval8) + CDbl(sval9) + CDbl(sval10)
    dTotal3 = CDbl(sval11) + CDbl(sval12) + CDbl(sval13) + CDbl(sval14)
    dTotal4 = CDbl(sval15) + CDbl(sval16) + CDbl(sval17)
    dTotal5 = CDbl(sval18) + CDbl(sval19)



    .TextBox1 = Format(dTotal1, "0")
    .TextBox8 = Format(dTotal11, "0")
    .TextBox2 = Format(dTotal2, "0")
    .TextBox9 = Format(dTotal12, "0")
    .TextBox3 = Format(dTotal3, "0")
    .TextBox10 = Format(dTotal13, "0")
    .TextBox4 = Format(dTotal4, "0")
    .TextBox11 = Format(dTotal14, "0")
    .TextBox5 = Format(dTotal5, "0")
    .TextBox12 = Format(dTotal15, "0")


  End With



With Me
    If dTotal1 = "" Then dTotal1 = 0
    If dTotal2 = "" Then dTotal2 = 0
    If dTotal3 = "" Then dTotal3 = 0
    If dTotal4 = "" Then dTotal4 = 0
    If dTotal5 = "" Then dTotal5 = 0


    If dTotal11 = "" Then dTotal11 = 0
    If dTotal12 = "" Then dTotal12 = 0
    If dTotal13 = "" Then dTotal13 = 0
    If dTotal14 = "" Then dTotal14 = 0
    If dTotal15 = "" Then dTotal15 = 0




    dTotal6 = CDbl(dTotal1) + CDbl(dTotal2) + CDbl(dTotal3) + CDbl(dTotal4) + CDbl(dTotal5)
    dTotal16 = CDbl(dTotal11) + CDbl(dTotal12) + CDbl(dTotal13) + CDbl(dTotal14) + CDbl(dTotal15)


       .TextBox6 = Format((dTotal6 / dTotal16), "Percent")

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you heard about arrays???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a big mess... You could use arrays, but, more important then that, you should care about types!

Anyway, your problem should be `CDbl(...)` applied on a empty string.

EDIT: Improvement suggestions

1. Declare your numeric variables as `Double`, instead of `String`
2. Replace your block `svalX = .CBX.Value` and `If svalX="" Then svalX=## Else svalX=##` with `If IsNumeric(.CB#.Value) Then sval#=.CB#.Value Else sval#=#`
3. You may use your `dTotal#=CDbl(sval#)+...`, but `CDbl` will not be needed anymore.

Comment: Yeah , I know it’s a mess. I have a very little knowledge on VBA. How can I fix it ? I am able to enter the values in user form and it does show the totals and percentage correctly but when i submit it , i am getting the error message.

Comment: Its worked  but now i am receiving an error message "Run time error 6 - Overflow" for the line item  .TextBox6 = Format(((dTotal6) / (dTotal16)), "Percent")

Comment: While debugging, check `dTotal16` value. Overflow may result from a very small `dTotal16`, so that `dTotal6/dTotal16` is very big.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably fix it by replacing all CDbl() calls with Val(), but that won't really solve the underlying problem.

As LS_Dev said: mind your data types. Try to avoid the use of Variants and don't store numeric values in string variables to use them as numeric again a bit further on.

Anyway, you're probably calling CDbl on a string that contains something that's not a number.
You're trying to avoid that higher up, but you must be missing something.
Are all "NA" really written in upper case, for example?  No other special cases besides empty strings and "NA"?

Comment: I made changes as suggested by LS_Dev . Now i am receving an error message         "Run time error 6 - Overflow" for the line item .TextBox6 = Format(((dTotal6) / (dTotal16)), "Percent")